# Multiply each row of a matrix which share same factor

Tags: r, matrix-multiplication

I have a matrix in R of the following form. The first column is a unique value which is shared by 0

```
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    1    2
[3,]    2    3
[4,]    2    5
[5,]    3   10
```

Results should look like the following:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    8
[2,]    2   15
[3,]    3   10
```

I have been looking for some time online but cant find an answer to this 'simple' problem without subsetting. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple option would be `aggregate`

```
aggregate(. ~ V1, as.data.frame(m1), FUN = prod)
#   V1 V2
#1  1  8
#2  2 15
#3  3 10
```

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
as_tibble(m1) %>% 
   group_by(V1) %>% 
   summarise_all(prod)
```

---

Or with `split`

```
sapply(split(m1[,2], m1[,1]), prod)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How would you expand this to m column without specifying each column?

Comment: @Max  If you have many columns and the first one is the grouping, then `aggregate(.~ V1, as.data.frame(m1), FUN = prod)`